# Media Queries for Canvas Element

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I'm currently teaching myself basic web design. When making a website responsive for different screen sizes (phone, tablet, computer, ...), from my understanding, you'd use CSS media queries. However, my website has a canvas element, and I learned the hard way (after wondering quite some time why it wasn't working) that you have to set the width and height not just in your CSS but also as HTML attributes of the element for it to work properly. So now my question is: What would be the best way to make a canvas element responsive, meaning it changes size based on screen size, when both of these things have to be changed for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can just "describe" your attributes in CSS. for example:

`<div class="responsive"></div>`

is your HTML so add

`.responsive{ ... width: 100%;}`

for the div to make it responsive.

Adding `width: 100%;` makes the attributes change their shape with the site.

Comment: Maybe I didn't formulate my question correctly. I have a canvas element with its width and height attributes (HTML) and its width and height properties (CSS) set to `500px`. Now I want this value to be `250px` (HTML and CSS) when the screen is smaller than 500 pixels in total. To change the CSS values I can do something like `@media (max-width: 500px) { canvas { width: 250px; height: 250px } }`. What I want to know is: How do I also change the HTML attributes when the screen is smaller?

Comment: theoretically you can just apply max and min width to make the div responsive. if that isnt what youre looking for check the CSS preprocessors like SASS to make if else statements. The problem is that SASS conditions are evaluated at compile time, not at run time. The other way is using 2 different images( 1 smaller 250px and 1 bigger 500px) and hide the bigger element with opacity: 0; when the page is getting smaller and show the other un-hide the other. If this comment was helpful, plz close the post, when not, just post another comment with the problem here.